# ESS with R sessions in different frames

Tags: window, frames, ess

When I have two frames open with different R sessions in each, such as

```
+------------+------------+    +------------------+
| # file.R   |            |    |                  |
| 1+4        |            |    | > 1+2            |
|            |            |    | [1] 3            |
|            | > 1+1      |    | >                |
|            | [1] 2      |    +------------------+
|            | >          |    | 3  *R:2*         |
+------------+------------+    +------------------+
| 1  file.R  | 2  *R:1*   |
+------------+------------+
```

When I'm in window 1 and eval a line or region into `*R:2*`, emacs replaces window 2's `*R:1*` with `*R:2*`, so I now have it open in both frame-1-window-2 and frame-2-window-3.

```
+------------+------------+    +------------------+
| # file.R   |            |    | [1] 3            |
| 1+4        | > 1+2      |    | > 1+4            |
|            | [1] 3      |    | [1] 5            |
|            | > 1+4      |    | >                |
|            | [1] 5      |    +------------------+
|            | >          |    | 3  *R:2*         |
+------------+------------+    +------------------+
| 1  file.R  | 2  *R:2*   |
+------------+------------+
```

And I have to manually change window 2 back to `*R:1*`.

Since the `*R:2*` buffer is visible in frame 2, is there a way to prevent emacs from changing window 2? I believe that there is logic where if sourced code produces output and the buffer is not visible, then it is made visible. I think the issue here is that it is not visible *in the current frame*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can work around this by using the function `ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step`, instead of `ess-eval-line-visibly-and-step`. The invisible version won't alter the current window arrangement. There isn't an invisible version for other `ess-eval-` functions, but most of them take a `vis` argument, so you could create your own wrappers if you like.

You could also try setting `ess-eval-visibly` to `nil`, which might solve the problem directly, and then you would only need to explicitly turn visibility back on when you wanted it.

Comment: Reassigning as `(define-key ess-mode-map "\C-c\C-n" 'ess-eval-line-invisibly-and-step)` was what did it. Thanks! (For the record, my `ess-eval-visibly` was already `nil`, no effect.)